# Cartesian product traverse in scalaz

Tags: scala, functional-programming, traversal, scalaz

In [Eric Torreborre's blogpost](http://etorreborre.blogspot.com/2011/06/essence-of-iterator-pattern.html) on the paper [Essence of the Iterator Pattern](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/iterator.pdf), he describes how the cartesian product of a traverse is also a traverse.

Can anyone show me an example of this using the [scalaz library](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Traverse.scala) as I can't figure it out. Let's say the problem is that, for a `List[Int]` I want to provide both of:

1. The `Int` sum of the elements in the list
2. A `List[String]` the elements of which are created by appending the "Z" to the String representation of the `Int`s

My understanding is that I can do this using `traverse` but in such a way as to only actually traverse my structure once, unlike this solution:

```
val xs = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val (sum, strings)  = (xs.sum, xs map (_.toString + "Z"))
```

**NOTE 1** - *I know that there are other ways of doing this and that I neither need traverse for this example, and nor is traverse even necessarily the clearest way to solve it. I am, however, trying to understand traverse, so am really looking for the answer to the question as stated*

---

**EDIT** - thanks to *missingfaktor* below for showing how to do this using `State`. I guess what I want to know is how I can compose the two independent calculations. For example; my functions are *notionally* as follows:

```
val shape = (_ : List[Int]) map (_.toString + "Z")
val accum = (_ : List[Int]).sum
```

I want to have these mechanisms of accumulation *independently* of one another and then choose whether to traverse my `List[Int]` using *either* or *both* of them. I imagined some code a bit like this:

```
xs traverse shape //A List[String]
xs traverse accum //An Int

xs traverse (shape <x> accum) //The pair (List[String], Int)
```

Eric implies that this is possible but I don't get how to do it ~ i.e. I don't see how to define `shape` and `accum` in such a way as that they can be composed, nor how to compose them.

**NOTE 2** *that `shape` and `accum` are not meant to literally be the functions with the signatures as above. They are expressions which have the type necessary to perform the above traversals.*

Comment: I don't understand the connection between cartesian product and the later half of your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Look at the implementation of `foldMapDefault` http://scalaz.github.com/scalaz/scalaz-2.9.1-6.0.4/doc.sxr/scalaz/MA.scala.html#64640. I think the key is in that `Const` that creates a phantom applicative functor. Note that `xs.foldMapDefault(i => (i, List(i))` does what you want.

Comment: @missingfaktor - in Eric's blog, he basically says this: 1. a `traverse` is a generalization of an iteration; it can accumulate values or build a structure with the same shape as the *traversee*. 2. the cartesian product of a traverse is a traverse. Hence you can do 2 calculations in one traversal

Comment: @oxbow_lakes, the only purpose I use `traverse` in my code is to avoid calling `map` and then `sequence`. i.e. `xss.traverse(f)` == `xss.map(f).sequence`. Useful in cases like, when you want to get `ValidationNEL[E, Seq[Seq[B]]]` from `Seq[Seq[A]]` by applying `A => ValidationNEL[E, B]`.

Comment: I think the idea of having independent "calculations" which can be combined arbitrarily is an awesome one. For example, I could have standard "functions" for getting stuff from a `M[Trade]` (where there is a `Traverse[M]`) such as: *inventoryP&L*, *tradingP&L*, *totalQtySold*, *totalQtyBought* etc etc. These could then be composed into calculations which happen in a single iteration. A beautiful example of FP enabling componentisation.

Comment: The problem is a function like `List[A] => B` is a whole-sequence operation and the details of what happens at each stage are pretty opaque. That IMO makes such automatic fusing of loops impossible. (Or perhaps it is possible and I am just unable to imagine it.)

Comment: It is possible because Eric's paper shows how you do it. See the scalaz7 examples below in Andreas' answer

Comment: @oxbow_lakes, see carefully. They are composing `A => B` and `A => C` into `A => (B, C)` and then applying it to `List[A]`. Since the details of each stage are available, loop fusion possible. What you are asking for is a different case than the one presented in Scalaz examples.

Comment: I think it is possible to achieve what Chris wants. You 'simply' have to identify the operations which need state to be decomposed. Chris can you give a bit more specific functions and data. TradinP&l seems opaque to me :)

Comment: @missingfaktor I think the functions are not composed. A key observation is how applicative is always the same on input type but can differ in output type. So using the applicative product it feeds each element of the traverse to the applicative, so that component can process it accordingly ( depending on state or just a mapping). In this way you have separated the computations. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AndreasScheinert, I don't think so. `traverse` can execute operations in a single loop, yes, but it can't do it when provided with `List[A] => B` and `List[A] => C`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AndreasScheinert, "I think the functions are not composed." I didn't get that. "Does that make sense?" To be honest, no. I don't understand EIP completely. Whatever I do, I have put into trying to solve the problem here.

Comment: I'm sorry and thinking about how to express the issue more clearly. Don't simply look at the functions you want to operate on the data. Each function (see word count example) is encapsulated into an applicative functor. This way each function can operate on the current input while being 'fused' (see terminology from WordCount example) into ONE applicative.

Comment: @AndreasScheinert, I am not convinced. Repeating what I said under my answer: Have a look at the Scalaz 6 example. On line#21, you have `charCountBody` which is `Char => Int`. On line#24, you have `lineCountBody` which is `Char => Int`. Line #31, the two are composed into `wordCountLineCountBody` which is `Char => (Int, Int)`. Line #33, `traverse` is passed `wordCountLineCountBody`. So, the fusion is possible because we have functions of type `A => B` and `A => C`. (contd...)

Comment: (contd...) What I am arguing is that such a fusion is not possible for functions of type `List[A] => B` and `List[A] => C`, which is what OP seems to be asking for.

Comment: @missingfaktor stackoverflow already suggests me to avoid extended discussions. I also feel that this is rather poor media. Switch to google+ ? tomorrow I could spare some time for IRC.

Comment: @AndreasScheinert, sure. Start a topic and tag me. I go by my real name there.

Comment: @missingfaktor - I didn't mean to imply that my examples `shape` and `accum` were literally as above (after all, they do not match the type of the arguments to `traverse`), merely that they were of a type which had the result that, when used in traverse, they computed the values as specified

Comment: @oxbow_lakes, okay. Even that (IMHO) is not possible. I'll try to ask this ask #haskell IRC to confirm.

Comment: @AndreasScheinert, I suppose you read the answer by retronym - the man who knows Scalaz best?

Comment: @AndreasScheinert - yes, of course. But it doesn't actually answer the question, which was about the cartesian product of a traverse being a traverse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm adding my own answer, building on Jason's one, to show different ways of traversing the list:

```
import org.specs2._
import scalaz.std.anyVal._, scalaz.std.list._
import scalaz._, std.tuple._
import scalaz.{Monoid, Applicative}

class TraverseSpec extends mutable.Specification {

  implicit val Sum = Monoid[Int].applicative
  implicit val Concat = Monoid[List[String]].applicative
  implicit val A: Applicative[({type λ[α] = (Int, List[String])})#λ] = Sum.product[({type λ[α]=List[String]})#λ](Concat)
  val xs = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

  "traverse - by folding the list with a Monoid" >> {
    val (sum, text) = Foldable[List].foldMap(xs)(a => (a, List(a.toString + "Z")))
    (sum, text) === (10, List("1Z", "2Z","3Z", "4Z"))
  }
  "traverse - with a function returning a tuple" >> {
    val (sum, text) = A.traverse(xs)(a => (a, List(a.toString + "Z")))
    (sum, text.reverse) === (10, List("1Z", "2Z","3Z", "4Z"))
  }
  "traverse - with 2 functions and 2 traversals" >> {
    val count   = (a: Int) => a
    val collect = (a: Int) => List(a.toString+"Z")

    val sum  = Sum.traverse(xs)(count)
    val text = Concat.traverse(xs)(collect)

    (sum, text.reverse) === (10, List("1Z", "2Z","3Z", "4Z"))
  }
  "traverse - with 2 functions and 1 fused traversal" >> {
    val sum     = (a: Int) => a
    val collect = (a: Int) => List(a.toString+"Z")

    implicit def product[A, B, C](f: A => B): Product[A, B] = Product(f)
    case class Product[A, B](f: A => B) {
      def <#>[C](g: A => C) = (a: A) => (f(a), g(a))
    }

    val (total, text)  = A.traverse(xs)(sum <#> collect)
    (total, text.reverse) === (10, List("1Z", "2Z","3Z", "4Z"))
  }
}
```

I think that the last example shows what you're after: 2 independently defined functions which can be composed to do just one traversal.

Answer (score 3):

Debasish Ghosh has written a nice [post](http://debasishg.blogspot.in/2011/01/iteration-in-scala-effectful-yet.html) on this topic. Based on the code in that post:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4)
res87: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> .traverse[({ type L[X] = State[Int, X] })#L, String] { cur =>
     |   state { (acc: Int) => (acc + cur, cur.toString + "Z") }
     | }
res88: scalaz.State[Int,List[String]] = scalaz.States$$anon$1@199245

scala> .apply(0)
res89: (Int, List[String]) = (10,List(1Z, 2Z, 3Z, 4Z))
```

**Edit:**

You have two functions `List[A] => B` and `List[A] => C`, and you want a function `List[A] => (B, C)`. That's what `&&&` is for. This won't fuse the loops though. I cannot imagine how it can be possible to fuse loops for such a case.

Fwiw, code:

```
scala> val shape = (_ : List[Int]) map (_.toString + "Z")
       val accum = (_ : List[Int]).sum
shape: List[Int] => List[java.lang.String] = <function1>
accum: List[Int] => Int = <function1>

scala> val xs = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
xs: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> (shape &&& accum) apply xs
res91: (List[java.lang.String], Int) = (List(1Z, 2Z, 3Z, 4Z),10)
```

**Edit 2:**

If you have functions `A => B` and `A => C` you can merge them into `A => (B, C)` using `&&&`. Now if `B : Monoid` and `C : Monoid`, you can use `foldMap` to get `List[A] => (B, C)`. This will do the stuff in one loop.

Code:

```
scala> val f: Int => Int = identity
f: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val g: Int => List[String] = i => List(i.toString + "Z")
g: Int => List[String] = <function1>

scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4).foldMap(f &&& g)
res95: (Int, List[String]) = (10,List(1Z, 2Z, 3Z, 4Z))
```

**Final edit:** (I swear I am not editing this again.)

Since these concepts have their origins in Haskell, I thought it'd be a good idea to re-post this question under <kbd>Haskell</kbd> tag, and I did. [The answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9191850/192247) seems to be consistent with whatever I have said in this thread. Hôpe this helps.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes, please check the edit. But I doubt if that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks again; I've added the links to the Scalaz 6 and 7 versions of the code which show how to turn the product of 2 traversals into a traversal. They're both ugly, which is a real shame as this sort of behaviour with a usable syntax would be a massive win. Having said that, perhaps I'll get used to the syntax

Comment: @oxbow_lakes, if you have understood that mechanism, can you please show us how to apply it to your specific case? because I honestly don't get it...

Comment: I don't have scalaz-seven in a REPL, but the example clearly shows how two traversals (one using state) are composed into a single traversal

Comment: @oxbow_lakes, see carefully. They are composing `A => B` and `A => C` into `A => (B, C)` and then applying it to `List[A]`. Since the details of each stage are available, loop fusion possible. What you are asking for is a different case than the one presented in Scalaz examples.

Comment: I don't see how they are doing that *at all*

Comment: I like the use of foldMap. Still doesn't specifically answer the question (I am trying to understand traverse, not necessarily come up with alternatives to a specific problem)

Comment: @oxbow_lakes, have a look at the Scalaz 6 example. On line#21, you have `charCountBody` which is `Char => Int`. On line#24, you have `lineCountBody` which is `Char => Int`. Line #31, the two are composed into `wordCountLineCountBody` which is `Char => (Int, Int)`. Line #33, `traverse` is passed `wordCountLineCountBody`.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes, the `foldMap` solution works in roughly the same manner. Follow the types.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes, the answer to your question is: `traverse` does not work the way you think it does.

Answer (score 3):

You don't see a big win here, as you're just promoting plain ol' Monoids into Applicatives so you fuse them together.

```
import scalaz.std.anyVal._, scalaz.std.list._, scalaz.std.string._
val Sum = Monoid[Int].applicative
val Concat = Monoid[List[String]].applicative
val A: Applicative[({type λ[α] = (Int, List[String])})#λ] = Sum.product[({type λ[α]=List[String]})#λ](Concat)

val xs = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
val (sum, text) = A.traverse(xs)(a => (a, List(a.toString + "Z")))
println(sum, text) // 10, List("1Z", "2Z", "3Z", "4Z")
```

Might as well just use `Monoid[(Int, List[String])]` for the stated problem:

```
import scalaz._, std.tuple._
val (sum1, text1) = Foldable[List].foldMap(xs)(a => (a, List(a.toString + "Z")))
println(sum1, text1) // 10, List("1Z", "2Z", "3Z", "4Z")
```

Things get more interesting if one of the effects you want to traverse with is a non-trivial Applicative, like `State`.

Comment: He requires a `(Int, List[String])`, not `(Int, String)`.

Comment: I edited the answer with the desired types. Notice that the order of the list result changes depending on traverse vs foldMap. I think that this is because the implementation of those 2 is different, using foldLeft vs foldRight.

Comment: Something I didn't realize also. You declare: ({type λ[α] = (Int, List[String])})#λ. This means that we don't even need to create a "Const" class (as in the "Essence of the Iterator Pattern") to get a phantom type (α in this case). Nice.

Comment: I like the idea of using the separate monoids together with foldMap to achieve multiple "simple" traverses. But my new year's resolutions this year were to understand both state & traverse, so this doesn't really answer the question

Comment: @Eric the reverse order might be a bug -- we're looking at a similar problem at the moment...

Comment: Yep, I just fixed that ordering problem. `traverse` with the monoidal applicative functor is precisely the same as `foldMap`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly that what you are looking for should be described in the scala-seven branch example: WordCount. It also involves state. I'm on mobile otherwise I would provide link.

Here's the links:

- [Scalaz 6](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/example/src/main/scala/scalaz/example/WordCount.scala)
- [Scalaz 7](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/example/src/main/scala/scalaz/example/WordCount.scala)

HTH Andreas

EDIT:

Ok some more explanations. I think the fundamental problem of your questions is how to compose functions or therefor applicative. This can be achieved through the product method on applicative.

https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Applicative.scala#L46

So you need to define applicative for your two functions shape and accum. Where accum would be modeled as a state applicative.

If we look at this line form the example:
val WordCount = StateT.stateMonad[Int].compose({type λ[α] = Int})#λ

It creates an applicative which 'works' (sorry my poor wording) which state. Usually on traverse you have only the current element nothing more. But if you want to compute on previous computations you need state so this create an state-applicative which returns 1 for each element it traverses ( see Monoid[Int].applicative).

Now to DO actually something we need to look at the atWordStart Method and you need to define a method which can work with the constructed WordCount applicative (using State)

Here is another example from scalaz 6, which is more simple. I think its important to observe the initialValue and how the transform1 method does :

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

object StateTraverseExample {

  type StS[x] = State[(Set[Int], Boolean), x] 

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("apparently it works " + countAndMap(Vector.range(0, 20)))
  }

  def transform1(i: Int, l: Set[Int], result: Boolean): (Set[Int],Boolean) = {
    if (result || (l contains i))
      (l, true)
    else
      (l + i, false)
   }

  def countAndMap(l: Vector[Int]): (Set[Int],Boolean) = {
    val initialValue=(Set.empty[Int], false)

    val counts = l.traverse[StS, Unit] { i => 
      state { case (set, result) => (transform1(i,set,result), println(i))   }
    } ~> initialValue
    counts
  }
}
```

I remember now because the topic interested me too. I asked why eric in his blogpost did not provide the applicative product. He said he it gave up wrestling with the type signatures. Arround that time jason fixed the WordCount example for scalaz7 ( six example did not provide action counting word)

Comment: If you fancy fleshing this out with how to apply it to the problem at hand (to help both me and missingfaktor), the points are yours!