# Is it possible for the presented case to be optimized into one loop?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, combinators

Suppose I have two functions `f :: [a] -> b` and `g :: [a] -> c`. I have the following two questions:

1. If I perform `(f &&& g) xs` where `xs :: [a]`, and if both `f` and `g` involve loops, is it possible for the compiler to optimize these two loops into one? (Please note that I am not asking whether some specific Haskell compiler implements this. I want to know whether such a thing is *possible*.)
2. Can the `traverse` function from `Traverse` type class help me have such an optimization with something along the following lines:

   ```
   traverse (someCombinator f g) xs
   ```

Comment: I think optimizations like in 1. could be performed by supercompilers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is theoretically possible to optimize this code, but very very difficult, because `f` and `g` might consume different amounts of the input list. Only when they consume the same amount, or `g` always consumes more of the list than `f` (or vice versa), would it be possible to perform the optimization. The Halting Problem prevents a compiler from detecting such conditions in complex code.

Only in simple cases, where both `f` and `g` use `foldr` internally, for example, would it be possible to perform trivial optimizations without further introspection.

The `traverse` function will not help you here, because there is no reasonable way of implementing `someCombinator` (How do you want to transform multiple calls of `a`'s into one `[a]` without serious hacks? And then you are back where you started anyways).

Your only real option is to make `f` and `g` into folders, so that they have the signatures `f :: a -> b -> b` and `g :: a -> c -> c`, meaning that the value of `b` and `c` can be computed incrementally. You can then use `\ a -> f a *** g a` to get a folder that you can use in a conventional (right- in this case) fold.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks a lot! I posted this question because I wanted to check whether what I said in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162256/cartesian-product-traverse-in-scalaz/9162706#9162706) (both in answer and in comments) was correct.